Laravel 11 Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configure
Getting an error

Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Method
Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configure
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php
on line 86

It works fine in the local development environment. Deployed on the server, this error is displayed by default. This occurs when the application loads, not during any specific action.
PHP 8.3
Laravel 11

How we can resolve this error?

Say details about in which point you are getting this error??

It works fine in the local development environment. Deployed on the server, this error is displayed by default. This occurs when the application loads, not during any specific action.

have you run composer install on production environment?  There are too many variables here to help without more information.

No i havent run as it is working on development environment

I encountered this issue and I removed the vendor folder and just had to run composer update as the references are not updated for Laravel 11, I upgraded from Laravel 10.
